# How are graph representations containing only (i, j) instead of both (i, j) and (j, i) named?

Tags: terminology, graphs, data-structures, weighted-graphs

When working with undirected graph algorithms using an adjacency-list type structure, it's sometimes enough to store a given edge `(i, j)` just stored in the list of edges of `i` or on the list of edges of `j`. Other times, it's important to have an `(i, j)` on `i` and a `(j, i)` on `j`.

I was wondering how do you call graph representations of one type and graph representations of the other type? Without concrete names to give to each one of them, code or even conversations about certain algorithms get confusing really fast.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking about directed versus undirected graphs (as in [Kyle's answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/43292/9550)) or about data structures where the presence of an edge $(i,j)$ implies versus does not imply the presence of $(j,i)$?

Comment: I'm asking for UNDIRECTED graphs where in some circumstances only having the edge defined in one of the vertices is enough while in others it is not. See the example I gave to Kyle: Prim vs Kruskal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second kind of representation is simply called the adjacency list representation.  It's a standard representation for graph data structures.

To my knowledge, there is no standard name for your first kind of representation; it's a weird and non-standard kind of representation.  That's probably because it's not sufficient for most algorithms on undirected graphs (most algorithms require more), whereas the adjacency list representation *is* sufficient for most algorithms on undirected graphs.  So, it would be rare to find situations where your first kind of representation is sufficient and useful.

You say that your first kind of representation is sufficient for Kruskal's algorithm, but this might be a bit misleading.  In fact, Kruskal's algorithm is fine with something even more minimal: merely having a list of all edges is sufficient for Kruskal's algorithm.  In other words, Kruskal's algorithm does not require the edge `(i,j)` to be associated with either `i` or `j` (it's OK if it's not associated with either, as long as you have a list of all edges).

In general, your first kind of representation does not seem like a natural choice for any graph algorithm that I can think of right now, so it's not surprising if it doesn't have a standard name.

Comment: This was just the answer I was looking for. You hit the bull in the eye regarding something I was already quite suspicious of: that the first kind of  representation isn't generally used. With that in mind, I'll just replace my code to just make use of the general "adjacency list" representation and everything will be fine.